save file csv same as original file
I’m writing a program to process CSV files, mainly to export a column, edit it, and then import it back. However, there’s an issue where my program isn’t saving the original data structure of the file. Instead, it’s creating a new CSV data structure, resulting in two files with different data structures. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.
def save_all(self):
    if self.selected_column is None:
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", "No column selected")
        return

    file, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", "Text files (*.txt)")
    if file:
        # Update the original data with the modified data
        column_index = self.df.columns.tolist().index(self.selected_column)
        for i, value in enumerate(self.df[self.selected_column].values, start=1):
            line = self.original_data[i].split(',')
            line[column_index] = f'"{value}"'
            self.original_data[i] = ','.join(line)

        # Write the modified data back to the file
        with open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(self.original_data[i])
        # Save the DataFrame to a new CSV file, preserving the original structure
        self.original_df.to_csv(file, index=False, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

original
result

you are writing to file both times

f.write(self.original_data[i]) is not in the for loop. So you're just writing the last element of self.original_data to the file.

You probably want to use f.write("\n".join(self.original_data)

You probably should be using the csv module to read and write the file. It will handle quoting properly for you.
